# Translate Layout left to right

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-animation

I tried to make a layout translation animate with this. But it only translate layout from left to right. But I need to translate right to left. So how should I do that?

```
aLayout.animate()
    .translationX(bLrLayout.getHeight())
    .alpha(0.0f)
    .setDuration(3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

> But I need to translate right to left.

just use negative number as `translationX` parameter

```
aLayout.animate()
    .translationX(-1000)
    .alpha(0.0f)
    .setDuration(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "translationX", 0, bLrLayout.getHeight()); 
anim.start();
```

and then if you want to return back

```
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "translationX", bLrLayout.getHeight(), 0); 
anim.start();
```